# Why writing to a FILE stream return random number?

Tags: c

I have the following code to open a buffer in the memory and write some data to it:

```
int main() {
    char buf[1000] = {0};
    FILE * os = fmemopen(buf, 1000, "w");
    fprintf(os, "%d", 100);
    fclose(os);

    printf("%d\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is some random numbers such as : `895734416` or a negative number... why is this happening?

Comment: The correct answer is, of course: the behavior is undefined. Answers like "it prints address of `buf`" are rather useless since the size of the address can easily be different from the size of `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf("%d\n", buf);` output the address of `buf` instead of the return value.

Comment: Yes; he probably wants `%s` instead of `%d`.

Comment: @texasbruce If you really want to see the address, you can use `%p`. I think the compiler will issue a warning in your `%d` case.

Comment: I forgot the number is converted to string during fprintf. I was trying to output the number

Comment: @texasbruce Cool! Now you get it :). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%d\n", buf);
```

This prints address of `buf` as its pointer variable.

If you really want to print its address use `%p` instead of `%d`.

If you want to print string use `%s`, but make sure your buffer read from file is null terminated.

Answer (score 1):

In the memory, all the data is stored in 1's and 0's. Its up to you how you interpret the data.

```
If you want the data to be printed as integer, use %d.
If you are printing a address , use %p.
If you want the data to be printed as char, use %c.
If you want the data to be printed as string, use %s.
```

In your example, use

```
printf("%d\n", buf);
```

to get the proper output.